# Reloading ember data from server

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to reload store data from the server after transitioning to a page.

The transition i'm referring in this case, is from an index page, to a specific page by id.

here is my code:

```
App.Board = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    boardItems: DS.hasMany('BoardItem'),
});

App.BoardItem = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    board: DS.belongsTo('Board')
});

App.BoardIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return {
            title: 'Boards List',
            boardItems: this.store.find('board')
        }
    }
});

App.BoardShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        // this.store.reloadRecord('BoardItem'); - tried this, didn't work :(
        var boardData = this.store.findById('board', params.board_id);

        return boardData;
    }
});
```

what happens is:
Index - loads a list of boards, with empty boardItems array (I don't want to load all of the data on the index)

Then clicking a link to a specific board, transitions to it, but the data is empty and no requests made to the server.

I tried various ways of reloading it, but all fails...

here is the debug info if it might help:

DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 ember.js:3521

DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 ember.js:3521

DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember.js:3521

DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> [Finding Records:](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/) If you provide a number or string as the second argument to `store.find()`, Ember Data will attempt to retrieve a record of that with that ID. This will return a promise that fulfills with the requested record:

```
App.BoardShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // Providing both the model name, and board identifier
    // Make sure the parameter exists.

    // console.debug('My board identifier is', params.board_id');

    return this.store.find('board', params.board_id); // => GET /boards/:board_id
  }
});
```